# How to distinguish method from attribute in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `cartridge` and `dosing_edge` models such that they have the relationships has_many and belongs_to respectively. By doing that I can call:

```
@cartridge.dosing_edges
```

to retrieve all dosing_edges that belong to a cartridge. And that works,
but cartridge model also has a dosing_edges attribute. How do I distinguish between method and attribute.

I mean, if I want to access `@cartridge.dosing_edges` not to call method `.dosing_edges` to retrieve all dosing_edges.

Or should I rename my dosing_edges attribute to be different.

Answer (score 7):

give different name to your `has_many` association.

```
has_many :all_dosing_edges, class_name: "DosingEdge"
```

I think this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you have `dosing_edges` attribute and `dosing_edges` method, when you call `object.dosing_edges` you'll get whatever method returns, cause having a method with the same name as attribute you basically overwrite the attribute, as the attribute of a class is a method too that can be overwritten. You could rename your `has_many`relations to something different.

Answer (score 1):

@MKumar is right that you should rename your association.  As some explanation, though, you can access attributes loaded from the database using the `[:attname]` hash-style notation (see bottom of answer)

So, when you say `@cartridge.dosing_edges` you're calling a **method**: this method will have been defined for you by default by rails to read the attribute, and you might have overwritten it with the methods added in by the `has_many` **macro**, which will add a variety of methods, including `dosing_edges` (assuming you haven't changed the name yet).

The default `dosing_edges` method would look like this:

```
def dosing_edges
  self[:dosing_edges]
end
```

`self[:dosing_edges]` is getting the attribute instance variable, rather than calling the method.